# How to duplicate slick slides?

Tags: slider, slick.js

I'm using slick-list to build an element where people can insert their own slides.
The slider is supposed to show 4 slides, but sometimes the number of slides doesn't reach that much and the slider bugs, making slides smaller (in width) than they were supposed to be.
I've tried to use infinite:true but it didn't go as I expected.
Here's how my slick is:
`

```
    $('.el-lista-slider-orcamento .itens').each(function(){
          $(this).slick({
            slidesToShow: 4
            ,infinite: true
            ,slidesToScroll: 1
            ,autoplay: false
            ,autoplaySpeed: 4000
            ,speed: 500
            ,easing: 'swing'
            ,swipeToSlide: true
            ,pauseOnHover: false
            ,pauseOnFocus: false
            ,adaptiveHeight: true
            ,prevArrow: $(".el-lista-slider-orcamento .setas .seta-anterior")
            ,nextArrow: $(".el-lista-slider-orcamento .setas .seta-proximo")
            ,responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1280
                    ,settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2
                    }
                },
        {
                    breakpoint: 768
                    ,settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    })
```

`
Is there a way to automatically duplicate the slides so I can reach the minimum of 5 (4+1) slides?
Thank you.

I've tried to set 'infinite' to 'true', expecting the slick-list to automatically duplicate the slides. I've seen some poeple complaining about this 'feature' (how they wish it didn't duplicate) but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Change `slidesToShow: 4` in `3.99`.

Learn more [here](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/1813#issuecomment-642694902).